# Incorrect page dimensions

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to create a simple document, on letter paper with 1-inch margins all around. Here's the simple document I'm working with:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\the\textwidth

\the\paperwidth

\end{document}
```

Given that letter paper is 8.5in by 11in (i.e., 612pt by 792pt), and the margins are 1in all around (i.e., 72pt on each side), I would expect the values of `\textwidth` and `\paperwidth` to be `612pt` and `468pt` respectively.

However, the actual result I get when I compile the above document is:

```
469.75502pt
614.295pt
```

I'm sure that some assumption I've made is incorrect, but I can't seem to find where I've gone wrong online. Can anyone explain why the actual results differ from my expectations?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Since the difference is so small it might be due to the difference between points and big points...

Comment: There's a difference between "printers' points" (72.27 per inch) and "big points" (aka Adobe points), 72 to the inch. TeX uses the "printers' points" convention.

Comment: Since `1in=72.27pt` and `614.295pt-469.75502pt=154.5399pt`, you have `154.5399pt/2=72,2699pt=1in`, so `1in` margin.

Comment: Is there a reference for this 72.27 figure? According to the Wikipedia article on points, the SI standard is 72pt = 1in, and the historical value found in "letter press printing" varied from 1pt = 0.18mm to 1pt = 0.4mm, and was never well-defined.

Comment: the values for the units of measurement are specified in the texbook, p.57.  possibly more accessible is victor eijkhout's "tex by topic" (`texdoc texbytopic` if you are using a tex live distribution), where these values are given on p.92 along with a bit of history.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the values used for the units of measurement are specified in the texbook, p.57.

1 in = 72.27 pt (printers' points)
1 in = 72 bp ("big points" as adopted by adobe)

probably more accessible to people who haven't bought the texbook is
victor eijkhout's "tex by topic" (`texdoc texbytopic` if you are using a tex live
distribution, or available from
[victor's web site](http://eijkhout.net/texbytopic/texbytopic.html)),
where these values are given on p.92 along with a bit of history.